# sum column data in csv file using php

Tags: php, csv, sum

I have a php code that, based on a form, creates a csv file with 2 columns containing numbers (quantity and price) and a subtotal column that multiplies these two numbers.

I would like to be able to add up all the cells in the "subtotal" column to get the total.

I am a beginner in php.
Can you please help me?

Thank you very much!

**My code :**

```
<?php
    $data_file = __DIR__ . '/data.csv';
    $subtotal = $_POST['quantity']*$_POST['price'];
    $total=[];

 
    if (isset($_POST['quantity'])) { //
        $stream = fopen($data_file, 'a');
        fputcsv($stream, [$_POST['quantity'], $_POST['price'], $subtotal], ',', '"', ' ');
        fclose($stream);
    }
    $stream = fopen($data_file, 'r'); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($record = fgetcsv($stream, 0, ',', '"', ' ')): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($record[0]) ?></td>
            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($record[1]) ?></td>
            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($record[2]) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</table>
<!-- The total should appear here, after the table-->
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use the array_sum property and to browse the subtotal column but I could not solve my problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us what you have tried and create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

By utilising the `while` loop you already have, you can increment the subtotal on each iteration, and then display the total afterwards:

```php
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $stream = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    $subtotal_sum = 0;

    while ($record = fgetcsv($stream, 0, ',', '"', ' ')): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($record[0]) ?></td>
            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($record[1]) ?></td>
            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($record[2]) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $subtotal_sum += (float) $record[2];
    endwhile;

    fclose($stream);

    $tax = $subtotal_sum * 0.1;
    $total = $subtotal_sum + $tax;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Subtotal:</td>
        <td><?=$subtotal_sum?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Tax (10%):</td>
        <td><?=$tax?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Total:</td>
        <td><?=$total?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is a cool little one-liner that achieves the same subtotal summing but requires you to fetch the data from the file again:

```php
echo array_reduce(array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv')), function($carry, $item) { return $carry + (int) $item[2]; }, 0);
```